# How to join two model in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a laravel project. I have to join two models Products and User. Where I need to get the results of a product as well as the details of the user who added it. I wrote the code below which isn't working. I'm wondering what'd be the solution.

Can anyone help me in fixing the issue?

**Products**

```
class Products extends Model implements AuditableContract
{    
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Auditable;
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $fillable = ['product', 'active_ingredient', 'brand', 'similar_to1', 'similar_to2', 'similar_to3', 'similar_to4', 'category_id', 'unit', 'jug_size', 'pallet_qty', 'tote_size', 'class', 'pallet_length', 'pallet_width', 'pallet_height', 'tote_length', 'tote_width', 'tote_height', 'pallet_avg_wt', 'restricted', 'hazmat', 'hazmat_notes', 'market_avg', 'quickbooks_id', 'trending', 'added_by', 'removed_by', 'deleted_at'];

    
    public function productUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id');
    }
}
```

**User**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable as AuditableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable implements AuditableContract
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Auditable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name','email','phone','device_token','password','approved','added_by','removed','removed_by','deleted_at'];


    public function userProduct(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Products', 'added_by');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So do you have an error message? How do you access the relationships? "It's not working" is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the relation of the Products model to be linked to the user so you create this inside the products model.

You have to modify this:

```
public function productUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class , 'id', 'added_by');
}
```

Where `user_id` is the foreign key in the Products table of the user and `id` is the primary key in the users table

Then to use that you simple do:

```
Products::with('productUser')->get();
```

That will retrieve all products with the user who added each product.

Since you want to retrieve the Products with the user info the function should be written inside the Products model.

The one you have in your user model is irrelevant for what you are trying to achieve so you can remove it.

Comment: Hey @pr1nc3,
Can you tell me after querying what I need in the products class then I need to grab the user info. ?

Comment: I posted in my answer the example how to use the Products class with the relationship. In there you have a nested collection with all the user info. Try to print_r it and you will see all the user info of the user who added the product. It's already there.

Comment: I tried it. Its giving me only the products not the user info

Comment: Do you access it? There must be a field if you use it correctly called productUser in your response. It may be empty if no user is assigned but in your print_r it should be there if you use it the way i included it in my answer. It's a part of your collection so access it like any other field.

Comment: `
 $product = Products::with('productUser')->get();
  dd($product[0][1]);
`
I can see only the product info. I cannot send the screenshot of result in the comments

Comment: why doing that? simple `dd($product);`  and loop. Check your product variable all the info is in that collection.

Comment: by dd, I'm getting all the 133 products. First of all, I need to see whether I'm getting the user Info or not

Comment: then dd the root $product  collection itself not [0][1]  or anything like that. Then you will see that what you are looking for is in there.

Comment: `  dd($product);`
I tried this. For you reference I'm attaching a screenshot in the question above

Comment: Ok, paste the code on how you actually use your model and how you call it in your controller.

Comment: `public function productUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'added_by');
    }
`




`$product = Products::with('productUser')->get();
  dd($product);
`

Comment: This is the model relation i wrote. Show me your controller itself that you are using the model. .

Comment: In the controller,

 $product = Products::with('productUser')->get();
  dd($product);

Comment: `$product = Products::with('productUser')->first(); `

`print_r($product->productUser);`

This is for only 1 product and retrieve the user of the 1st product basically. Check this out. For all the products you need to loop around the whole collection

Comment: It's working cause you got only 1 product. For all the products you will need the `get()` function but as i said you simple loop the collection using foreach and you get everything you need. The way to access productUser is the same you only need a loop around your overall collection, then you do what you did with the `first()` function. I am glad i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Product belong to a user and user will have products.

in products

```
function productUser(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "added_by", "id");
}
```

in users for one to many relation

```
function products(){
 return $this->hasMany(Product::class, "added_by", "id");
}
```

if the relation is one on one then it should be like

```
function product(){
   return $this->hasOne(Product::class, "added_by", "id");
}
```

To get the products with their respective users

```
$products = Products::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->with('productUser')->get();
```

Comment: `
$products = Products::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
dd($products->productUser);`
I want to access the user info.
It's giving an error saying 
**Property [productUser] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: $products = Products::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->with('productUser')->get();
Use with() ,
get() returns array of model. so you can use with() to get the relation.

Comment: I tried that. I can see only the product information but not the user info

Comment: check the relations property of the product object in the output of dd() or just convert the result to json and then try dd() like dd(json_encode($products));